# reload page without 'Retry' message using javascript in classic asp

Tags: javascript, post, asp-classic

I have a classic asp page and a button which when clicked needs to reload the page, I have tried using a lot of options

window.location.reload() is working fine in Chrome but its giving a 'To display the webpage again,the web browser needs to resend the information you've previously submitted' message every time its loaded. The same problem in Firefox.
There are no payments or any kind of data-entry on this page, just a view page with print button.
Is there any other work around for this.

Any help appreciated. TIA

```
 $('#btnPrin').click(function () {            
        window.location.reload();            
    });
```

Comment: Hi .. anyone .. ideas please

Comment: See in the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Only suggestions: I cannot make comments yet, and I do not know ASP.

Can the result of the function cause a cancellation?

```
 $('#btnPrin').click(function () {            
        window.location.reload();            
        return false;
    });
```

Force a full reload of the page form the server:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Perhaps an alternative to reload():

```
window.history.go(0);
```

Or any of these 535 other methods:

http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html

As for the exact mechanism which alerts/prompts the user about resending form data, there is a chance it could be a setting in the browser only the user can adjust. That would also make it brand dependent.